# conditional EMA pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

|  | condition | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 10:01:00 | True | 1 |
| 2016-01-01 10:02:00 | False | 2 |
| 2016-01-01 10:03:00 | True | 3 |
| 2016-01-01 10:04:00 | False | 4 |
| 2016-01-01 10:05:00 | False | 5 |
| 2016-01-01 10:06:00 | False | 6 |
| 2016-01-01 10:07:00 | False | 7 |
| 2016-01-01 10:08:00 | False | 8 |
| 2016-01-01 10:09:00 | False | 9 |
| 2016-01-01 10:10:00 | True | 10 |

Here is the code to build the df I typed above:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                  'year': [2016]*10,
                  'month': [1]*10,
                  'day' : [1]*10,
                  'hour': [10]*10,
                  'minute': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df)
df['condition'] = [True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True]
df['value'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
df = df[['condition', 'value']]
```

I want to have a column that shows the exponentially weighted moving average (halflife=5minutes) of values when the condition column is True.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out:

```
df['value_conditional'] = np.where(
    df['condition'] == True,
    df['value'],
    0
)

df['ewm_conditional'] = df.ewm(halflife=dt.timedelta(minutes=5), times=df.index).value_conditional.mean()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).